# Given 3 elements, return the number of the element with a given class

Tags: javascript

Given some HTML like this:

```
<a>foo</a>
<a class="active">bar</a>
<a>baz</a>
```

What JavaScript will return the number of the element with the active class? For instance, if these were returned by an array like in: `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));`, I would like to return the number `1`, representing the second element in the array.

Here is what I have tried, it just keeps returning `1` and `2`:

```
var tagCount = 0;
var tagArray = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
for (var a = 0; a < tagArray.length; a++) {
    while (tagArray.className[a] !== "active") {
        tagCount = tagCount + 1;
    }
}
```

I do not need all `a` tags, just those inside of another element.

Comment: Flagged for off-topic, asking for a tutorial. You are showing minimal effort on your part, and simply asking SO to do something for you

Comment: @HunterStevens I will add the code I have tried.

Comment: The question isn't clear enough. Do you want to check all `a` tags in an html? or just between certain tags? Is it in javascript only or is jQuery also a possibility?

Comment: @Goowik I clarified in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.indexOf.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), combined with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```js
var i = [].indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), document.querySelector('a.active'));
console.log(i);
```

```html
<a>foo</a>
<a class="active">bar</a>
<a>baz</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly, and is very elegant.